# How to use relative paths in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, path

This is going to be a short, nevertheless complicated question. Let me try and explain what I am trying to accomplish.

I've got a config file `config.yml`

```
# src/Company/HappyBundle/Resources/config/config.yml
company_happy:
    import:
        attachments_path: "@CompanyHappyBundle/Resources/public/attachments"
```

I'm trying to get the `attachments_path` parameter in a Command. I do this using the following line:

```
$this->container->getParameter('company_happy.import.attachments_path');
```

Now, how can I convert @CompannyHappyBundle to the actual path?

#### Update

If you have any information on better ways to do this, this is always welcome. What I'm trying to do is to save attachments to the bundle's public folder.

Comment: Why do you need that? Why not to store attachments under `web` directory? Your Bundle is your reusable component that need to be isolated. It is wrong way to store files that was uploaded by users in the Bundle's home.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me the right way to get the files to the web directory in symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store your attachments at the bundle's home directory. Also  you have wrong definition for parameter. All parameters in Service container must be located under `parameters` section.

As you can see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html) you need to create Form with `file` field. Then fill this form with Request data and then use `move()` method upon it to move file in any location you need. The most popular place for it - `web/uploads` directory.

```
public function uploadAction()
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('attachment', 'file')
        ->getForm();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $dir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads';
        $someNewFilename = '...';

        $form['attachment']->getData()->move($dir, $someNewFilename);

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a value in your `parameters.yml` as following:

```
# parameters.yml

parameters:
    company_happy.import.attachments_path: "@CompanyHappyBundle/Resources/public/attachments"
```

Then call it the same in your controller as you currently are.